# I2C Current monitor for low current (0-2A) application

Tags: current-measurement

I want to monitor current draw from a solenoid and also the total current draw of my PCB. The solenoid specifications are 24V, 11W, which results in a current draw of 0.458A.

I have considered hall effect current sensors, but it seems that they usually range from at least 0-5V, and the resolution is then 0-2.5V because it can measure positive and negative currents (at least this is my understanding, please correct me if I'm wrong). Since I want to measure a maximum current of 2A, this seems like a bad solution, giving low resolution readings. Therefore, I found the INA230 and INA260 I2C Current and Power monitor chips from TI, which seems to be a better choice for my application.

However, I find it difficult to understand if they are any good at measuring low currents (0-2A in my case) at 24V. How can I determine if for example the INA260 is a good choice for measuring this range?

Also, to me it seems like the main differences between INA230 and INA260 are that 230 requires external shunt resistors, while 260 have them built in. Are there any pros/cons to selecting one or the other?

**EDIT:**
I now see that neither of the chips are possible to buy at the moment. So I want to ask the same, but for the LTC2945 IC.

Comment: There are Hall effect sensors that are unidirectional, giving you double the resolution. I know Allegro makes some that have a maximum current of just 5 A too, so your 0-2 A would fit pretty well in that.

Comment: If you are looking at the Hall sensors that have a hole for wire, you can loop the wire through n times and reduce the range proportionally. For example, 5x through would make a 5A FS sensor 1A FS.

Comment: It all depends on your selection of sense resistor.   You'll want to select a value that stays within the voltage range of the part when you are operating at your max current.